# AppEngine: Step-by-Step Debugging

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine

While working with AppEngine locally (i.e. using dev_appserver.py), is there anyway to do a step-by-step debugging? It is a too old fashion to use logging.info() or similar functions to show the values of all the variables in the code and decide where the error is.

Answer (score 15):

To expand a little bit on codeape's answer's first suggestion:  Because dev_appserver.py mucks about with stdin, stdout, and stderr, a little more work is needed to set a "code breakpoint".  This does the trick for me:

```
import sys
for attr in ('stdin', 'stdout', 'stderr'):
    setattr(sys, attr, getattr(sys, '__%s__' % attr))
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

You'll have to run `dev_appserver.py` from the command line rather than via the GUI App Engine Launcher.  When the `pdb.set_trace()` line is executed, you will be dropped into the `pdb` debugger at that point.

Comment: Can you please explain your a code a bit more? Why is the setattr necessary here? What if I don't put this code?

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. I get "Illegal seek" error.

Comment: The for loop is simply a shortcut for writing ``sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__; sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__; sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__``

Comment: Handy factoid: this works well for debugging Python GUI applications too!

Answer (score 12):

Eclipse PyDev supports debugging and AppEngine.

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html

Answer (score 8):

If the local appengine process is a normal python process you have a couple of options:

1. In your code, place "code breakpoints": `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. Run `dev_appserver.py` as normal, and the python debugger will break when it reaches the line with the code.
2. Run `dev_appserver.py` in pdb. From the shell: `$ python -m pdb dev_appserver.py`. To set a breakpoint, use the command `b filename.py:linenumber`. Then use the `c` command to continue. See http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

See the [pdb module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html).

Comment: The first one didn't work for me. It just doesn't stop and I seem to get BdbQuit error!

Comment: The second one did work for me, but it is not convenient. It breaks from the beginning, while I want to have a break point at a certain point of my code.

Comment: To set a breakpoint, use the command "b filename.py:linenumber". Then use the "c" command to continue. See http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

Comment: To figure out which command to run, I just start the app in the AppEngineLauncher and grep for it in the process list:
`ps x | grep dev_appserver` then I stop it and launch it from the command line, but I add `-m pdb` directly after the python command.

Answer (score 3):

[PyCharm Professional Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) enables step-by-step debugging out of the box.

If you're willing to go through a few setup steps, the free version, PyCharm Community Edition, can be configured to work with Google App Engine python too. You won't get all the advantages of  PyCharm Professional Edition such as deployment, but you'll be able to do step by step debugging and get code navigation and auto-completion working.

To enable debugging, edit the PyCharm Run/Debug configuration by setting:

- Script: App Engine's dev_appserver.py
- Script parameters: `--automatic_restart=no --max_module_instances="default:1" .`
- Working directory: your base project folder (the one which contains the app.yaml file)

For more detailed instructions, explanations, and how get code completion working in aup PyCharm CE project, see http://www.enkisoftware.com/devlogpost-20141231-1-Python_Google_App_Engine_debugging_with_PyCharm_CE.html.

If you're working on Windows and you want to use PyTools (Microsoft Visual Studio Community) to debug python for GAE, see http://www.enkisoftware.com/devlogpost-20140814-1-Python_Google_App_Engine_debugging_with_PyTools.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily Visual Studio Code these days.

First you need to install a python module **debugpy**

```sh
pip install debugpy
```

Then install Python Extension for Visual Studio Code.

Now start the server with the following command:

```sh
cd /path/to/python/project
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py .
```

In Visual Studio Code Debug, create a configuration inside "lauch.json"

```
{
    "name": "Python: Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "connect": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 5678
    }
  }
```

Afterwards, you can just set the breakpoints, and click run "Python: Attach".