# Getting control of `pdb` back from App Engine in Emacs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, emacs, pdb

I have a Python Google App Engine application I'd like to debug on the dev server, in Emacs.  I have a `pdb` executable file I created so that debugging would play nice with Emacs:

```
$ which pdb
/usr/bin/pdb
$ cat /usr/bin/pdb
#/bin/sh
exec python -m pdb "$@"
```

In Emacs, I `M-x pdb` and get prompted `Run pdb (like this):` to which I enter `pdb /usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py /Users/[person]/path/to/app/directory`.

This starts off nicely.  I get a window with a `(Pdb)` prompt, I can set breakpoints successfully in early parts of the code like some of the `dev_appserver.py` file and use commands like `n` to step through line at a time.  I can then enter `c` to continue with program execution.

Problem is, as soon as app engine has printed out its usual startup `INFO` messages (to the same buffer the Pdb session is taking place in), I don't get a `(Pdb)` prompt back again, so I can't enter any more `pdb` commands.  This is both my first time using `pdb` and my first time debugging in Emacs, so maybe I'm just doing something plain wrong.

Comment: I suggest first trying to get `pdb` and app engine to work together outside of `emacs` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497672/appengine-step-by-step-debugging) ... Then try to add another layer of complexity.

Comment: This is not how you use pdb in appengine.  Read the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Debugging_with_PDB  pdb input is hooked up to stdin/stdout of the supervisor process of the dev appseverver.  You also may have to limit threads.  Once you get this working, then can look at how you might run the dev_server from emacs.  Wouldn't have a clue how you might do that, but get  basic pdb working inside the dev server first.

Comment: @TimHoffman can you explain the difference in how PDB works if you insert calls into the source code versus calling the `dev_appserver.py` with `-m pdb` from the terminal?  My understanding is that if you call it from the terminal it just breaks at the first line of code (in this case in `dev_appserver.py`)?  It may not be an option, but I'd certainly prefer to not have to modify the source code just because I want to debug it.

Comment: @mgilson Good point.  Following http://stackoverflow.com/a/4498552/129475 (python pdb from the terminal not Emacs) I'm still experiencing the same issue though.

Comment: appengine is running the actual server request in a subprocess connected via pipes;  So you are unable to directly set break points.  You can if you use something like winpdb or boa constructor which supports remote debugging.  By invoking pdb in code and you have access to the console then stdin/stdout are available in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

@TimHoffman has a good answer.  The dev server re-routes pdb from the various actual server processes, so you're not going to be able to launch pdb from the command line.

An alternative which might work is to launch the dev server from your emacs command line without pdb, and insert a pdb breakpoint in your code

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

I typically debug with this, but not via emacs.

Comment: yep, i'm basically using pdb in the code now and debugging from the same terminal window I called the dev_appserver from.  I don't like it, but I haven't found a good workaround.